# Return a boolean indicator or enums in web service

Tags: web-services

I am designing a web service xml result and would like some advice.

Everything here has been done previously with an xml boolean "indicator" returned for example

```
<isAMemberOfGroup1>y</isAMemberOfGroupA>
```

I think it would be better/clearer and more maintaineable to return a list of enums such as:

```
<membership>group1</membership>
<membership>group2</membership>
<membership>group3</membership>
```

Either the membership is there or not.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is largely a design question on how to efficiently structure the xml - efficient for the consumers of your webservice. I don't see how this is related to Java, Enum or Jersey. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: That's possible. It's just a matter of how you parse your object to a xml representation.

Comment: True the xml is not Java or Jersey however it will be consumed by Java apps only, and they will be doing ugly things every time a new membership group is added or deleted. I will be going with the enums. Tks for your input.